# How to run npm start automatically on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I have been trying to learn npm recently to use for a website. I am wondering though how it is used in a website, like do you have to run the command "npm start"? How is this integrated in a live website? Like would I have to run "npm start" every time the user enters the main page for example? And if yes, how is this done?

On visual studio code I can easily do it by running "npm start" in the terminal, but I am basically wondering how this is done without visual studio code and in a live website?

Comment: This entirely depends on what you're building. Try searching for _"deployment"_ strategies for your chosen tech stack / framework / etc

Comment: `npm start` is meaningless without knowing what `script` is being executed (as per your package.json `scripts` property - but no, in general you wouldn't use npm start to respond to a http request, since there'd be nothing listening to know when the user "enters the main page" to know when to start listening for requests from the user - a (http) server needs to be running before a user can "enter the main page"

Comment: You are right. for my project, npm start executes nodemon, which basically lets npm listen at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

During development, we use localhost as a server.

In real time, a dedicated server will run your program. In this server, you provide instructions on how to start your application.

**Example**:- If app.js is the starting point, you provide instructions to start this file.

If an application is provided as a docker container, the docker file will contain this instruction.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-npm-start-though-docker/

If an application is deployed to a cloud service provider like Heruko, you customize the instruction as per the service provider.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploying-node-js-applications/

Comment: what if I use a vps server? or does that depend on the hosting platform? .. particularly, I want to know how I can use vps server and let npm listen to my custom domain instead of localhost. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use pm2 to start and keep my node apps running on the server. Using PM2 you can close the terminal and the apps keep running.

Examples using PM2...

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name "Your App"
```

//show running apps

```
pm2 status
```

//show server logs while running apps

```
pm2 log
```

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/